# Why is my live reload in grunt watch task not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, watch, livereload

This is my code. I've setup the watch task to livereload when html/css/js is changed. I used a grunt file from another project to make this one, and so far it looks identical. I don't know what I can do to make it work again, so any advice is appreciated.

```js
'use strict'
module.exports = function(grunt) {
 grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

  connect: {
   server: {
                options: {
                    port: 6001,
                    base: './',
                    livereload: false,
                    open: {
                        target: 'http://localhost:6001'
                    }
                }
            }
  },

  watch: {
   options: {
                livereload: true
            },
   html: {
    files: ['index.html', 'src/html/*.html'],
    tasks: ['htmlhint'],
   },
   sass: {
    files: ['src/sass/**/*.scss'],
    tasks: ['sass', 'cssmin'],
   },
   js: {
    files: ['src/js/**/*.js'],
    tasks: ['jshint', 'uglify'],
   }
  },

  copy: {
        build: {
          cwd: 'src/',
          src: ['**/*.html'],
          dest: 'build/html',
          expand: true,
          
        },
        index: {
         src: ['index.html'],
         dest: 'build/html',
         expand: true
        }

     },

     clean: {
      build: {
                src: ['build/**/'] // Destination Folder
            }
        },
 });

 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-htmlhint');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');

 grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean', 'copy', 'sass', 'cssmin', 'jshint', 'uglify', 'htmlhint', 'connect', 'watch']);
 grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean']);
    grunt.registerTask('conn', ['connect']);
    grunt.registerTask('css', ['sass', 'cssmin']);
    grunt.registerTask('html', ['htmlhint']);
    grunt.registerTask('js', ['jshint', 'uglify']);
    grunt.registerTask('production', ['build', 'css', 'js', 'html', 'connect']);
    grunt.registerTask('serve', ['connect', 'watch']);
};
```

```html
<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

Some how this isn't working. Does it have something to do with the port? Or maybe it has something to do with my grunt tasks?

Comment: You should add the log. Is the "watch" task executed? maybe grunt stay stuck at the "connect" task.

Comment: Do you mean: 


Running "connect:server" (connect) task
Started connect web server on http://localhost:6001

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "index.html" changed.
Running "htmlhint:src" (htmlhint) task
>> 11 files lint free.
It seems to be running

Comment: try using another port. or you can also use grunt-connect

Comment: tried another port, isn't working though :(

Comment: Yes, connect is running, but Is the watch task running ?

I think the connect task don't stop and dont give the hand to the watch task.

Edit your post and add the full log stack.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm quite new to grunt. What do you mean by full log stack? Thanks